# Query where column is in another table - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables called **categories**, **seasons** and **movies**.

**categories table**

```
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
| id |   name  |    slug    | created_at  |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
|  1 |    It   |  it-2017   |  SOME TIME  |
|  2 | Another |  another   |  SOME TIME  |
|  3 |SpiderMan| spider-man |  SOME TIME  |
|  4 |  Cars 3 |   cars-3   |  SOME TIME  |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
```

**seasons table**

```
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
| id |  number |category_id | created_at  |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
|  1 |    1    |     2      |  SOME TIME  |
|  2 |    2    |     2      |  SOME TIME  |
|  3 |    1    |     3      |  SOME TIME  |
|  4 |    3    |     1      |  SOME TIME  |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
```

**movies table**

```
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
| id |   name  |    slug    |  season_id  |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
|  1 |  Pilot  |   pilot    |      1      |
|  2 |  Second |   second   |      1      |
|  3 |  Third  |   third    |      1      |
|  4 |  Fourth |   fourth   |      1      |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
```

And I made that URL is going to something like this

*mywebpage.com/serie/{category_slug}/season-{season_number}*

But where I go to this URL, query is going to show all movies in all seasons.
Not the season from current category.

My Controller

```
public function getMovies($category_slug, $season_number)
{
  $categories = Category::where('slug', $category_slug)->get();
  $seasons = Season::with('movies')->where('number', $season_number)->get();

  return view('routes.getMovies', compact('categories', 'seasons'));
}
```

And my view **getMovies.blade.php**

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach ($seasons as $season)
      @foreach ($season->movies as $movie)
        Season - {{ $season->number }}
        {{ $movie->name }}
        {{ $movie->description }}
      @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And my output is like Season 1 from all categories, but I want only to show seasons from current **Category**.

Comment: Try this `$seasons = Season::with('movies')->where('number', $season_number)->where('category_id', $categories->id)->get();` !!

Comment: @Maraboc, it gives me an error

*Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.*

Comment: So try this `$category = Category::where('slug', $category_slug)->first();
$seasons = Season::with('movies')->where('number', $season_number)->where('category_id', $category->id)->get();
return view('routes.getMovies', compact('category', 'seasons'));`

Comment: It works better ..., but this is show **movie** in all seasons from current category.

eg.  Movie Cars has 3 seasons with multiple episods and this episods is going to show in all of seasons from category **Cars**.

Comment: I don't think so because we have `->where('number', $season_number)->where('category_id', $category->id)` it's where and where !! what is the value of `$season_number` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure have set the right relation on your models

Movie Model

```
public function season()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Season::class, 'season_id');
}
```

Season Model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

Then, the following will get all movies with a specific season number and specific category slug

```
$movies = Movie::whereHas('season', function ($season) use ($season_number) {
    $season->where('number', $season_number);
})
->whereHas('season.category', function ($category) use ($category_slug) {
    $category->where('slug', $category_slug);
})
->with('season')
->get();
```

and in view

```
@foreach ($movies as $movie)
    Season - {{ $movie->season->number }}
    {{ $movie->name }}
    {{ $movie->description }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$categories = Category::where('slug', $category_slug)->first()->id;

$seasons = Season::with('movies')->where('number', $season_number)->where('category_id', $categories)->get();
```